How to override a plugin parent dependency in Maven from the command line?
Running maven at 3.9.8 using the following command which applies maven-dependency-plugin:
mvn -X -U -e clean compile package --settings $MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML dependency:copy-dependencies -DincludeScope=runtime -DexcludeScope=provided

Consolidating dependencies by calling copy-dependencies is required for a vulnerability scan; therefore it is preferable to use maven-dependency-plugin for this task.  By default, maven at 3.9.8 includes maven-dependency-plugin at 3.7.0.
The maven-dependency-plugin at 3.7.0 has jdom.jar at 1.1 as a great-great-grandparent dependency through parent dependency maven-reporting-impl at 3.2.0.  jdom.jar at 1.1 was quarantined in our nexus by vulnerability software and can no longer be retrieved to complete the build relying on dependency plugin; all these builds are failing.
I can force maven-dependency-plugin to 3.7.1 via the following change, but it still references maven-reporting-impl at 3.2.0 (and therefore jdom at 1.1):
mvn -X -U -e clean compile package --settings $MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.7.1:copy-dependencies -DincludeScope=runtime -DexcludeScope=provided

Version 4.0.0-M15 of maven-reporting-impl does not use jdom as a dependency, however I am unable to figure out how to specify the version of maven-reporting-impl via the command line (or via the settings.xml file, a last resort).  Official documents suggest adding -DpluginVersion= as below, but this does not work; it still is included at 3.2.0.
mvn -X -U -e clean compile package --settings $MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.7.1:copy-dependencies
-DpluginVersion=org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:4.0.0-M15
-DincludeScope=runtime -DexcludeScope=provided

I have moved the position of -DpluginVersion= to various positions, but all fail to access the 4.0.0-M15 version.  I suspect this is probably because maven-reporting-impl is not a plugin but a parent dependency of a plugin.
How can I override maven-reporting-impl version so when dependency is called it uses the 4.0.0-M15 version, preferably from the command line?  What is the proper syntax to use?

Why do you want to do this from command line? Why not just put it into the POM? You should also check if it would not be better to allow jdom 1.1 for builds only because the risk is probably low.

@JFabianMeier - there are about 50 different projects and therefore 50 different pom.xml using a central script, which would require modifying 50 different pom.xml to compensate for something that is part of the maven build executable and not part of the actual project.  If this could be done in a central settings.xml, I would consider it.

Many companies have a company parent POM from which everyone inherits. There, you fix versions and also fix problems.

And to elaborate on my other comment: It often leads to problems to block certain "dangerous" versions of JARs for every possible application. It is better to look at the vulnerability and block it only for e.g. publicly facing web sites.

1 - yes, I'm working on the parent pom solution before I came back to this.
2 - I have no control over the quarantine system and the red tape involved to de-quarantine is not worth the hours spent.  Still would prefer a command-line override considering it exists for the call to dependency itself.
